# Find a Poincaré map associated with the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Find a Poincaré Map associated with the system \begin{align}\dot{r}&=(r-3)(r^2 -4) \\ \dot{\theta} &=4\end{align}

I have the following so far

\begin{align}\int\frac{1}{(r-3)(r^2-4)}dr &= \int dt \\ \therefore t + c &=  \int\frac{1}{(r-3)(r^2-4)}dr\end{align}
Now, using Partial fractions, we can rewrite the right-hand-side as

\begin{align} t + c &=  \int\bigg(-\frac{1}{4 (r-2)}+\frac{1}{20 (r+2)}+\frac{1}{5 (r-3)}\bigg)dr \\ &=-\frac{1}{4}\ln|r-2| + \frac{1}{20}\ln|r+2| + \frac{1}{5}\ln|r-3| + k\end{align}

How can I reduce this into a a form $r(t) = \dots ~$?

I require this in order to continue with the rest of the question.

Comment: One can go one step further and note that $$\frac{(r(t)+2)(r(t)-3)^4}{(r(t)-2)^5}=c\,e^{20t},$$ for every $t$, for some constant $$c=\frac{(r(0)+2)(r(0)-3)^4}{(r(0)-2)^5},$$ but there is no way to invert this using only usual functions.